# Why does firefox immediately request https when I type in http URL?

Tags: http, firefox, ssl, https

I have an IIS7 ASP.NET webserver bound to both http and https.

So, I type in http://test35-control.musac.school.nz into Firefox 7.0.1.
In the server logs I immediately see

> 2011-11-09 04:57:16 130.123.148.35 GET / - 443 - 130.123.96.22
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:7.0.1)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/7.0.1
>   200 0 0 123

In Firebug, Net panel [with persist selected] shows the first request as 
https://test35-control.musac.school.nz/

So, Firefox seems to ignore the fact that I've asked for http and go to the https site instead. Why is that?

Probably answered on the net, but there are too many generic terms for googling...

The same seems to happen in all other browsers I have on hand too (IE8, Chrome, Opera).

Comment: Have you got site bindings for both of the protocols? And have you got redirection turned on?

Comment: Yes to bindings, but no to redirection; I was about to start setting up redirects when I noticed it was working already!

Comment: There is a proxy involved. This could perhaps be doing something, but that wouldn't stop the net panel in firebug from showing the original http: get. I'm going to install Ethereal and verify exactly what's going out...

Comment: And you don't have the URL Rewrite Module installed? If you don't then it must be something to do with the proxy. IIS won't redirect unless something is explicitly telling it to. Are you only getting 443 requests logged and no 80 / 8080's? That tells me that proxy is redirecting as http requests never hit the server.

Comment: Does the http:// request redirect to the https:// one normally?  And if so, does Firefox just have the redirect cached?  If you clear the cache, do you see both requests?

Comment: As far as I know, we do not have the rewrite module installed, but I'm not 100% sure how to verify this. In IIS modules I don't see it. I do see UrlRoutingModule-4.0, UrlMappingsModule, and HTtpRedirectionModule (amongst many others of course)

Comment: Hi Boris, there is a client side Javascript redirect from http to https. I suspected browser caching, but I have cleared the cache and history completely, and indeed tried other browsers...

Comment: Aha! Firebug net panel IS lying. Wireshark shows http get (port 8080 to the proxy). This then returns a 302 response with Location: https://... and Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0. So the question is now, who is doing that 302 response.

Comment: OK, excluding the proxy, it still redirects to https, so it's definitely IIS. But what part of IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it turns out it's not doing that; it's just that:

- Firebug net panel doesn't log all traffic
- IIS sometimes logs redirected requests out of order**

Our system is doing the redirect using a custom 403 error page with a server-side 302 redirect written in Asp.net. This was done 2 years ago by someone who has now left, and no-one could remember :)
The application is set to require SSL (in IIS manager, SSL settings), to force the 403 error when accessing via HTTP.
We have bindings for http and https.

Other things that might have been confusing me:

- auto-configured proxy - only making it difficult to trace things, as far as I can tell it is not doing a redirect.
- browser cached 302 - though it's not supposed to, thats a temporary move
- IIS logs need to be flushed to be up-to-date (is there a better way to view them in real-time??) - netsh http flush logbuffer
- IIS logs in UTC :)

Well that was interesting.

** IIS seems to log the redirect requests in a different order sometimes, e.g.

```
2011-11-10 02:17:42 130.123.148.35 GET / - 443 - 130.123.96.22 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:7.0.1)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/7.0.1 302 0 0 3
2011-11-10 02:17:42 130.123.148.35 GET /LoginPage.aspx ReturnUrl=%2f 443 - 130.123.96.22 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:7.0.1)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/7.0.1 302 0 0 4
2011-11-10 02:17:42 130.123.148.35 GET /Dashboard/MyDashboard.aspx - 443 - 130.123.96.22 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:7.0.1)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/7.0.1 302 0 0 4
2011-11-10 02:17:42 130.123.148.35 GET /LoginPage.aspx ReturnUrl=%2fDashboard%2fMyDashboard.aspx 443 - 130.123.96.22 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:7.0.1)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/7.0.1 200 0 0 4
2011-11-10 02:17:42 130.123.148.35 GET / - 80 - 130.123.96.22 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:7.0.1)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/7.0.1 302 0 0 83
```

## 2

```
2011-11-10 02:08:52 130.123.148.35 GET / - 80 - 130.123.96.22 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:7.0.1)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/7.0.1 302 0 0 7
2011-11-10 02:08:52 130.123.148.35 GET / - 443 - 130.123.96.22 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:7.0.1)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/7.0.1 302 0 0 4
2011-11-10 02:08:52 130.123.148.35 GET /LoginPage.aspx ReturnUrl=%2f 443 - 130.123.96.22 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:7.0.1)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/7.0.1 302 0 0 7
2011-11-10 02:08:52 130.123.148.35 GET /Dashboard/MyDashboard.aspx - 443 - 130.123.96.22 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:7.0.1)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/7.0.1 302 0 0 3
2011-11-10 02:08:52 130.123.148.35 GET /LoginPage.aspx ReturnUrl=%2fDashboard%2fMyDashboard.aspx 443 - 130.123.96.22 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:7.0.1)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/7.0.1 200 0 0 102
```

Answer (score 3):

For posterity, an unlikely reason Firefox would issue the request to the typed URL over HTTPS (on default port 443) is if it had previously gotten a response from the server over HTTPS with the `Strict-Transport-Security` header with a `max-age` value that still applies.

To explain, to the best of my knowledge -- although I can't for the moment locate a Mozilla resource that definitely confirms this -- Firefox will by default use HTTP protocol if you type an address. At least that can be confirmed empirically.

However, when a request is made over HTTPS and the response contains the aforementioned HTTP header, Firefox will, in compliance with [the specification](//tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6797) and for the time duration specified by `max-age`, always and only use HTTPS for every request to the server, never HTTP.

In your case, it might have happened you were testing HTTPS and the server was configured to serve the header with some `max-age` value that hasn't expired -- Firefox will then basically behave as if you typed `https://` in front of your otherwise scheme-unprefixed URL, not `http://` as by default.

This behaviour is not Firefox specific -- it applies to its contemporaries like Chrome, Opera, Vivaldi, Brave, and their derivatives, assuming they adhere to the same specification.

Comment: Nice addition for modern day situation. The original question was 8 years ago (2011). HSTS only existed in draft form at the time :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2010/06/encrypt-web-https-everywhere-firefox-extension) extension installed, do you? Unlikely if it's happening on the other browsers as well. I would think that the HTTP server is serving up a redirect to the HTTPS version of the site, and the browser just follows that.

Comment: Thanks, but no. I did notice that extension while trying to google for this problem. I just tried disabling all my addons in case (firebug, downloads in tab, download helper). No difference.

Comment: I was not aware that that was the issue.  I will try a couple of links with the add-on/extension disabled.